# How do I run javascript functions stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with instructions inside it, such as:

```
runThis= "alert(); if(1>2) { alert("NO WAY");}";
```

How do I run the code inside runThis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eval(runThis);
```

But you shouldn't write code this way, it is difficult to manage.

Do it like this instead :

```
runThis= function () {
  alert(); 
  if(1>2) { 
    alert("NO WAY");
  };
}
```

then just call runThis

Answer (score 2):

The dirty way to do this would be

`eval(runThis);`

This is, however, not reccommended at all.

Alternatively, wrap it in a function

```
runThis = function(){ 
  // statements go here
}
```

And then you can call it `runThis();`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this kind of thing, you can use the eval() function:

```
eval(runThis);
```

However this is not a recommended approach as it can lead to all kinds of difficult to diagnose bugs and errors

A better approach is to write a proper function with the code you wish to execute, and then assign it to a variable and invoke it via the variable:

```
//Assign function to variable
runThis = function(){ 
  alert();
  if(1>2) {
    alert("NO WAY");
  };
}

//Later, invoke the function
runThis();
```

Comment: OK well if I downvoted all the `eval`s I'd take a big hit, that's not fair for you. Removing.

Comment: @Steve, I've made some edits to address some of your concerns. Firstly, I'm pointing out that eval is not recommended, and secondly, I have taken down the w3schools link. Nonetheless they asked a question and I'm providing an answer - I don't know if for some reason they really, really can't avoid having the function as a string, so at least this gives them an option

Comment: Noted. 
I removed it 6 minutes ago :)

Answer (score 0):

```
code = "alert('test');";
eval(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

***WARNING: THIS IS A HORRIBLE PRACTICE! DO NOT DO THIS!***

```
eval(runThis);
```

once you escaped your inner quotes properly.

Answer (score 0):

`eval(runThis);`

But it's not recommended. Just remember `eval() is evil`.

Answer (score 0):

Eval will execute a string but you would be better off defining run this as follows. And call it like any function.

```
var runthis = function(){
     //code  here
}
```

But if you need to execute a string call eval.

eval(runthis);